# MVC 5 - The field CreateDate must be a date

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have default date in field = **15-06-2014** and after submit I see error communicate: **The field CreateDate must be a date**. - why?

My ViewModel:

```
public class CommentViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "CreateDate is required")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid date")]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public CommentViewModel()
    {
        CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

My action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    CommentViewModel commentViewModel = new CommentViewModel();

    return View(commentViewModel);
}
```

My view:

```
@model WebApplication5.Models.CommentViewModel


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{    
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreateDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreateDate)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreateDate)

    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
}


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: What is the input format you are using? in your example you are using hypens to separate. try using the "/" instead

Comment: So why default date show as 15-06-2014, not as 15/06/2014?

Comment: I just built a little test application with the code you've posted above and wasn't able to replicate the issue.  Is there anything else at play here that you're not showing? What browser are you using as it may be an issue with the client-side jQuery validation.